# Is the following language $L$ regular?

Tags: regular-language

$L=\{ww^Rv\mid v,w\in \{a,b\}^+\}$
Is $L$ regular ?

**Edit**

Is it ok?
Let $p$ will be length of pumping lemma. Then, $a^pb(a^pb)^Rv\in L$.
When $a^p(a^pb)^Rv = xyz$
 $p\ge |y|\ge 1 $
So $a^{p+k}b(a^pb)^Rv$. Because of the fact that $a^{p+k}b(a^pb)^R$ is not palindrom then $a^{p+k}b(a^pb)^Rv\notin L$. Thanks to pumping lemma we have $L$ is irregular.

Ok ?

Comment: If $w^R$ is the reverse of $w$, then why do you say that $L_1$ is regular?

Comment: I have no idea why $ww^{R}$ should be regular.
The Language of Palindrome isn't regular because you can't store an arbitrary word to check if it inverse follows.

Comment: look again pleas

Comment: Your proof does not work. The word $aa$ is a palindrome and thus $aav \in L$ for each nonempty word $v$.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why you talk about $aa$, I got word $a^pb(a^pb)^Rv$

Comment: For $p \geqslant 2$, $a^pb(a^pb)^Rv = aaw$, with $w = a^{p-2}b(a^pb)^Rv$ and thus $a^pb(a^pb)^Rv \in L$.

Comment: It is incredible, but I really don't understand. Look :
$p$ is length of pumping lemma. For every word in our language exists partiton such that ( conditions ) And I got word $a^pb(a^pb)^Rv \in L$. ($v$ is anywhere).  $a^pb(a^pb)^Rv = xyz$. Because of $|xy|\le p$ , $xy^2z =  a^{p+k}b(a^pb)^Rv \notin L$. What's up ?`