# Understanding pumping lemma - length $p$ - in connection with other thread

Tags: regular-language

I create this thread in connection with [Is the following language $L$ regular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214508/is-the-following-language-l-regular)
I would like to show you why I dont understand where I am wrong.
I would like to ask question:
$p$ - length of pumping lemma.
If $L$ is regular then exists $p$ for every word $s\in L$ such that $|s|\ge p$ there is partition of word $s=xyz$ meet expactations:
$(1)\forall_{i\ge 0} xy^iz\in L$
$(2)|y| > 0$
$(3)|xy|\le p$

And now fragment of solution from book:
Show that $\{w|\#_1(w)=\#_0(w)\}$ is irregular. (# denotes count).
Given $s=0^p1^p$. We may say that (thanks to (3)) $y$ contains only 0s.

And analogically, $L=\{ww^Rv\mid v,w\in \{a,b\}^+\}$ I say that for $s=a^pb(a^pb)^Rv=xyz$.
Then $y$ contains only symbols $xy^2z=a^{p+k}b(a^pb)^Rv$. And now you see that $a^{p+k}b(a^pb)^R\notin L$ (because it is not palindrom). 
Where am I wrong ? Pay attention to the fact I do analogically to book.

**Edit**
$X\cap L = Z$

if $Z$ is irregular then $X$ or $L$ is irregular.
Let $X=(ab)^+(ba)^+$ is regular.
$X\cap L = Z = \{(ab)^n(ba)^k| k > n\} $

Because of fact that $Z$ is irregular and $X$ is regular then $L$ is irregular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in thinking that $a^{p+k}b(a^pb)^R\notin L$. In fact this word *is* in $L$. To see this, let $w=a$ and $v=a^{p+k-2}b(a^pb)^R$; then $a^{p+k}b(a^pb)^R=ww^Rv$, so $a^{p+k}b(a^pb)^R\in L$. *Every* word that begins with two identical letters is in $L$.

Comment: I edited. Could you look again, please ?

Comment: @user220688: Yes, that works. You could also use the Myhill-Nerode theorem and show that the strings $aba^{2n+1}b$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ have distinguishing extensions.

Comment: I try to use Myhill-Nerode. Is it easy to solve it using pumping lemma ?

Comment: @user220688: It cannot be done using the pumping lemma: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232423/non-regular-language-that-satisfies-pumping-lemma).

Comment: Is it extension: $a^{2n+1}bab$.  When we get $aba^{2n+1}b$. Then $aba^{2n+1}ba^{2n+1}bab\in L$, but for every $n\neq k\in\mathbb{N} aba^{2k+1}ba^{2n+1}bab\notin L$  Ok ?

Comment: @user220688: Yes, it’s fine.

Comment: @user220688: You’re very welcome!

Comment: Maybe, you help me here ;) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234397/find-cfg-for-language-aw-2-bw

Comment: @user220688: I’ll take a look, though it be a while before I get to it.

Comment: thanks, every clues is very nice for me