# Is there a context-free but non regular language, which still meets the requirements of the regular pumping lemma?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

> Is there a context-free but non regular language, which still meets the requirements of the regular pumping lemma?
>   Regular Pumping Lemma: $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:\forall w \in L:{\mid
>  w \mid} \geq n: \exists x,y,z\in \Sigma^*$: 
>   \begin{align} i)&w=xyz\\
>  ii)& {\mid y \mid} \geq 1\\ iii)& {\mid xy \mid} \leq n\\ iv)& \forall
>  i\in \mathbb{N_0}:xy^iz\in L 
> \end{align}

Is there any $L$ with $L\in CFL$ and $L\notin REG$ but still meets the regular pumping lemma from above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non regular language that satisfies pumping lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232423/non-regular-language-that-satisfies-pumping-lemma)